# SSRS: how to display grouped rows in different cells of a list

Tags: reporting-services

The dataset returns rows of the below shape.

```
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Department | Full Name     | Bonus Recommen (%) |
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Accounting | Jane Doe      |     3.00          |
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Accounting | Phil Morris   |     1.05          |
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Accounting | Aimee Jackson |     1.27
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Production | Paul McDonald |     2.47
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
| Production | John Doe      |     1.98
+------------+---------------+-------------------+----
```

I'd like to individual tables depending on the department, i.e. something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------
|            Accounting 
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Full Name     | Bonus Recommen (%) |
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Jane Doe      |     3.00           |
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Phil Morris   |     1.05           |
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Aimee Jackson |     1.27           |
+---------------+--------------------+----

+------------------------------------------
|            Production
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Full Name     | Bonus Recommen (%) |
+---------------+--------------------+----
| Paul MacDonald|     2.47           |
+---------------+--------------------+----
| John Doe      |     1.98           |
+---------------+--------------------+----
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: use filter expression on tablix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the layout by grouping:

1. add a table and drop fullname and bonus into the table. Remove the
   extra blank column since RS will create 3 column table by default
2. At the bottom of the IDE right click row groups and click **Add Group**
   -> **Parent Group**, and select Department from the dropdown list
3. Right click the Department cell at data row level, from context menu
   select **Insert Row** -> **Inside Group - Above**
4. Copy the cell title (or simply input Full Name and Bonus) to this newly added row
5. Repeat step 3 to add another row
6. Select two cells from newly added row, right click and click **Merge
   Cells**
7. Copy Department cell value to this merged cell
8. right click the left most column (department) and select **Delete Columns**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've learned a lot with you suggestions. As a matter of fact, I'm going to modified some of the reports I've created earlier. Thanks you so much.